# How to add button style on Fancybox gallery from one link?

Tags: fancybox, gallery, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox to popup photo galleries and videos on a project. I've been successful in setting up a photo gallery from one link, but I haven't been able to figure out how to change the style of that gallery. I prefer the "button-helper" style.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="img/dog1.png" title="Caption will go here.">
    <i class="icon-camera"></i>“The pictures</a>
    <a class="hide fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="img/dog2.png" title="Caption will go here."></a>
    <a class="hide fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="img/dog3.png" title="Caption will go here."></a>
```

This works perfectly, but I would prefer the button-helper style of gallery. I was able to get the button-helper gallery to work, but not from a single link. It only worked when all of the thumbnails were visible on the page.

How do I change the style of a gallery from a single link?

Here is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'fade',
                closeEffect : 'fade',
                prevEffect : 'fade',
                nextEffect : 'fade',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect: 'fade',
  prevEffect: 'fade',
  nextEffect: 'fade',
 });
});


    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    fitToView   : true,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
});
```

Comment: What is the jQuery code you are using?

Comment: @JFK I'll post the jQuery I'm using above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="img/dog1.png" title="Caption will go here."><i class="icon-camera"></i>“The pictures</a>
<div style="display: none;">
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="img/dog2.png" title="Caption will go here."></a>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="img/dog3.png" title="Caption will go here."></a>
</div>
```

... so you are not actually hiding the images but the parent container.

On the other hand, you don't seem to use all different fancybox custom scripts so I would rather delete them all and simply use this code :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // set here all the option you really need/want
    modal: true,
    helpers : {
      buttons: { 
          position: "top" // or "bottom"
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I could definitely cut down on the jQuery. Was planning to do that at the end. That HTML is giving me the same effect, so I tried this: <a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="img/dog1.png" title="Caption will go here."><i class="icon-camera"></i>“The pictures</a>
<div style="display: none;">
    <a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="img/dog2.png" title="Caption will go here."></a>
    <a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="img/dog3.png" title="Caption will go here."></a> 
But that did not work either. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you binding fancybox like `$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({...`?

Comment: No, the only jQuery I've done is what I put above. Can you send the full binding code?